# How to make a 4x4 sudoku solver in java

Tags: java, algorithm

Can you guys give me some ideas for algorithm for 4x4 sudoku solver in java laugauge. I am currently having diffcultly in figuring out a agorithm. I have read wikipedia page for 9by9 solver, but maybe you guys can simplify the idea of it

Comment: If you were able to Google to find the wikipedia page, I am sure you can find an example online. This seems like a basic interview or home work question.

Comment: like i saw the puesducode for it, but i didn't understand it that well, so im asking if you guys can simiplify the idea litle bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a page that explains this with a 4x4 grid.  By the way, you really should try Googling before asking a question here. I just searched "sudoku solver example program" to find this.

http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/solving-sudoku-with-matlab.html